# How to get XML element attribute values in single quotes in REST API XML response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson-dataformat-xml

REST API produces the response in JSON and XML format. I am using Jackson to get XML elements as required but when I use @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true), values get in double quotes; how to get them in single quotes? Thank you.

Please consider a getter and setter for each attribute. here we have a list of routepoints, to get longitude and latitude values in  element in XML format added JacksonxmlProperty.

```java
     public class Root implements Serializable {
        private double distance;
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
        private double seca_distance;
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper (localName = "routepoints")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "point")
        private List<RoutePoint> routepoints;
    }
    
    public class RoutePoint implements Serializable {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private double lon;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private double lat;
    }
```

JSON Response:

```json
                {
                    "distance": 10898.387781160134,
                    "seca_distance": 674.09075,
                    "routepoints": [
                        {
                            "lon": 9.87,
                            "lat": 53.54
                        },
                        {
                            "lon": 9.87,
                            "lat": 53.54
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

XML Response:

```xml
                <route>
                  <distance>10898.387781160134</distance>
                  <seca_distance>674.09075</seca_distance>
                  <routepoints>
                     <point lon="9.87" lat="53.54"/>
                     <point lon="9.87" lat="53.54"/>
                  <routepoints>
                <route>
```

In XML response longitude (lon) and latitude (lat) attribute values in  element coming in double quotes, Any idea how to get those values in single quotes like lon='9.87' lat='53.54'? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes or double quotes should not matter. It's perfectly fine. Clients of this data will be able to parse it both ways.

Most libraries generate double quotes AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am refactoring the legacy code, in old response they are appending single quotes manually to values; I know it's not the best way that's the reason we are refactoring the code and trying to get the response as it is with annotations.

Comment: @Vamsi: But the point is that any XML parser worth its salt should be able to handle either. Clients shouldn't care which is used. Any client that is broken by this change is almost certainly broken in other ways. I can imagine some brittle tests being broken by this (tests which expect a very specific format) but that's all that *should* be broken by it. (And might also be broken by changes in insignificant whitespace etc.) If you feel your use case *really* has a good reason to care about this, please clarify that in the question.